# Delimiting a square in a coordinate system

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a board of 3 squares by 3 squares, which looks like this:

[image: Board]

The edges for each square, are represented as a tuple, containing starting coordinates and ending coordinates for the edge, as such:

```
((0,0), (0,1))
```

The twist is that at any point one of these edges can be removed. Leaving a square incomplete.

I'm attempting to write an algorithm in Python which detects squares on the board.

The data for the board is kept in a dictionary, in which the keys are the edges and the corresponding values are booleans representing if the edge is currently in place or not, it looks a little like this:

```
   Graph=  {((0, 0), (0, 1)): True,
            ((0, 0), (1, 0)): True,
            ((0, 1), (0, 2)): True,
            ((0, 1), (1, 1)): True,
            ((0, 2), (0, 3)): True,
            ...}
```

Currently, if I iterate through all the points on the board, I can only find out if there are complete 1x1 squares, by finding the nearby edges and checking if they're set as True or not in my graph. I'm currently finding edges near the starting point (which is always on the bottom left corner of a square) by doing this:

(`(x,y)` being the coordinates of the starting point)

```
left = ([edge for edge in graph if (x,y) in edge and (x, y+1) in edge])
right = ([edge for edge in graph if (x+1, y) in edge and (x+1, y+1) in edge])
top = ([edge for edge in graph if (x, y+1) in edge and (x+1, y+1) in edge])
down = ([edge for edge in graph if (x, y) in edge and (x+1, y) in edge])[0]
```

I'm using list comprehension here because the orientation of the edges is currently arbitrary, and instead of directly accessing (e.g.) `((1,0),(1,1))` in the graph, I need to search it to see if it has either that or `((1,1),(1,0))`.

Regardless of that little complication, what's troubling me is that I can't come up with a way to check for squares of larger dimensions. For example, I also need to check for 2x2 and 3x3 (if `(0,0)` is the starting point) squares, and for that my method is unsustainable.

For example, I need to detect a 2x2 square starting in `(0,0)`, I want to detect the square whose edges are:

```
left: ((0,0),(0,1)), ((0,1),(0,2))
right: ((2,0),(2,1)), ((2,1),(2,2))
top: ((0,2),(1,2)), ((1,2),(2,2))
bottom: ((0,0),(1,0)), ((1,0),(2,0))
```

I apologize for the messy code and appreciate any hint or tip.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could write a function that accepts a lower-left coordinate and an edge size, and returns the edges that such a square would include.  Then, you just have to check whether all of those edges exist in your pile.  You will probably want to sort your pile of edges to make that easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a starting point.  Again, this assumes the dictionary is stored with the tuples sorted.  That's not hard to do.

```
def make_square( x,y,n ):
    for i in range(n):
        yield (x,y+i),(x,y+i+1)
        yield (x+i,y),(x+i+1,y)
        yield (x+n,y+i),(x+n,y+i+1)
        yield (x+i,y+n),(x+i+1,y+n)

print(sorted(list(make_square(0,0,3))))

# Find 2x2.

for x in range(2):
    for y in range(2):
        if all(Graph[edges] for edges in make_square(x,y,2)):
            print( f"2x2 Square starts at {x},{y}" )

# Find 3x3.

for x in range(1):
    for y in range(1):
        if all(Graph[edges] for edges in make_square(x,y,3)):
            print( f"3x3 Square starts at {x},{y}" )
```

"make_square" returns a list of the edges of a square that starts at (x,y) for size n.  It does one segment from each of the 4 sides, then moves to the next segment.  The "yield" is just a cute way of returning multiple things one at a time.  It would also have been possible to store each of those in a list, then return a list at the end.  The "yield" makes it a generator.

So, in the loops at the bottom, we loop through each possible starting position for a square.  In a 3x3, looking for 2x2 squares, they can start at (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), or (1,1).

So, for each starting position, we have `make_square` generate the edges for that square.  The "all" function returns true if all of the elements of the list inside are true.  So, for each edge in the list that make_square returns, we use the value of Graph[edges].  If those all returned true, "all" returns true, and we have a winner.

In the last loop, there's only one starting position for a 3x3 square.  I left the loops in because it was symmetrical, but of course they aren't necessary.  I hope you can see how this could be generalized to larger squared.  For example, if you had a 5x5 square:

```
for subsquare in range(1,5):
    for x in range(5-subsquare+1):
        for y in range(5-subsquare+1):
...etc...
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, although I don't really understand the dynamic behind this, could you provide a little description?

Comment: I will edit with a description.  The `yield` is perhaps a bit tricky, but it works here.

Comment: Thank you. After reading and testing I understand why and how it works.  Also, what would be the best approach regarding scaling this method to an N-sized board? Perhaps englobing the for-cycle in another for-cycle?

Comment: I added that to the description. Instead of separate loops, you'd just have yet another loop, ranging through the sizes of the possible subsquares.

Comment: Super in-depth and straight to the point. Thank you so much, also thumbs up for explaining yield!